# Single link to all mobile video stream formats

Tags: video-streaming, protocol

I'm doing some video streaming to different kinds of mobile devices(with the help of Wowza Media Server). And I need to have a **single URL to serve all device types**(e.g. `mobile://funny-cats.mp4`).

A dumb and straightforward solution is to use a link to a web-server, which checks the type of client and redirects to appropriate URL. But this sounds like a pretty common task so I wonder if there's already any handshake protocol between server and mobile device to agree on which media type is supported? (Like SDP?)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, most websites just rely on the client telling the website what kind of device it is.  Then it happens server side.  It's also software implemented, making it easy to modify.

Comment: That sounds like the method I mentioned in my question. So the way to go is to check `User-Agent` header on server and redirect appropriately?